# EXCEPT operator query to differentiate between new and changed rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, except

I am using the EXCEPT Operator to compare data between two tables (as part of a final import I want to compare "today's data" with "yesterday's data" and only finally import new and changed rows.)

It (EXCEPT) seems to be exactly what I need, but does anyone know a way I could extend it so that in the resulting data subset I was able to differentiate between rows that are new and rows that are changed?

Comment: To detect "changes" you need a key. With equal key and different values on other columns, it's a update. With no matching key it's a new record. In any case, you can't use `EXCEPT` with all columns if you want to differentiate these 2 operations.

Comment: Thanks. All I am doing is 
select * from newdata
except
select * from olddata
and it seems to be doing what I want it to - i.e. isolate new records which weren't in olddata and also those rows which were in olddata but have changed values in newdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the technique from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27126344).

```
--Demo setup
set nocount on
drop table if exists #T1
drop table if exists #T2
Create table #T1 (Id int, OtherData varchar(10))
Create table #T2 (Id int, OtherData varchar(10))

insert into #T1(Id,OtherData) values(1,'NewRow')
insert into #T1(Id,OtherData) values(2,'ChgRowB')

insert into #T2(Id,OtherData) values(2,'ChgRowA')

-----------------------------------------------
--The actual query
-----------------------------------------------

-- NEW
SELECT A.*, 'NEW'  AS 'CHANGE_TYPE'
FROM #T1  A
LEFT JOIN #T2  B ON B.ID = A.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
UNION
-- MODIFIED
SELECT B.*, 'MODIFIED'  AS 'CHANGE_TYPE'
FROM (
        SELECT * FROM #T1 
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM #T2
    ) S1
INNER JOIN #T2  B ON S1.ID = B.ID;
```

---

```
| Id | OtherData | CHANGE_TYPE |
|----|-----------|-------------|
| 1  | NewRow    | NEW         |
| 2  | ChgRowA   | MODIFIED    |
```